# How to work with a react-geocode promise inside a generator function

Tags: reactjs, promise, redux-saga, google-geocoder

I'm trying to use the react-geocode plugin, and I put it inside a generator function in redux saga. I'm pretty new to promise and redux-saga, so I'm not sure this is the best way to deal with this plugin or with promises in general. I was thinking of using $scope to call the lat and lng variables outside of the promise, but im not sure if that's the best way to solve this problem. In the end, lat and lng return undefined but don't catch an error.

```
 function* getSearch() {
    const address = yield select(state => state.location.address);
    Geocode.setApiKey("****************");
    console.log(address)
    const a = Geocode.fromAddress(address).then(
        response => {
            const { lat, lng } = response.results[0].geometry.location;
        },
        error => {
            console.error(error);
        }
    )
    try {
        yield put({ type: 'SUCCESS_FETCH_LOCATION', payload: {lat: a.lat, lng: a.lng}})
    } catch (error) {
        console.log(error);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you yield a promise, redux-saga will wait for that promise to resolve, and then resume your code once it has the result:

```
function* getSearch() {
  const address = yield select(state => state.location.address);
  try {
    const response = yield Geocode.fromAddress(address);
    const { lat, lng } = response.results[0].geometry.location;
    yield put({ type: 'SUCCESS_FETCH_LOCATION', payload: { lat, lng }});
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
  }
}
```